# Account for change in variable in while loop

Tags: r

My data.frame `Calculations` is structured as follows:

```
head(Calculations)

     Name        x        y  Sample  Time
1  Thomas  26.6627 -12.3782       1  0.01
2  Thomas  26.6564 -12.3711       2  0.02
3  Thomas  26.6497 -12.3635       3  0.03
4 Caitlin  28.6423 -14.3555       1  0.01
5 Caitlin  28.6353 -14.3472       2  0.02
6 Caitlin  28.6269 -14.3385       3  0.03
```

Whereby `SampleRate <- 100` and `k <- as.integer(SampleRate)`
whilst `m_velocity<- matrix(NA, length(Calculations$x))`

I wish to run the following while loop to calculate velocity over time:

```
attach(Calculations)
i <- 2
while(i < length(x) - k){
  m_velocity[i] <- sqrt(sum((x[i] - x[i-1]) ^2, (y[i] - y[i-1]) ^2)) / (1/SampleRate)
  i <- i+1
}
```

However, this does not restart for each `Name`. For example, the first velocity entry for Caitlin would be NA and not calculated from the X and Y coordinates from Thomas.

**UPDATED**
I used the following code to obtain Velocity:

```
Calculations %>%
  arrange(Name) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(Velocity = sqrt( (x - lag(x) )^2 + (y - lag(y) )^2 ) * SampleRate)
```

but when I checked the first entry of `Sample` for each `Name` using `ddply(Calculations,.(Name),function(x) head(x,1))` velocity is still being calculated from the previous person's X and Y coordinates. Any suggestions?

**SOLVED**
My issue was stemming from first loading `dplyr` then `plyr` which creates issues as stated [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/347).

Comment: Do you always have the same numbe of lines for each name?

Comment: @Ouistiti Yes, the data is collected over the same length of time so there will be the same number of rows per person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without a while loop.

```
library(dplyr)

calculations %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(velocity = sqrt( (x - lag(x) )^2 + (y - lag(y) )^2 ) * SampleRate)
```

Comment: When I run this and test to see the first entry of each `Name` using `ddply(Calculations,.(Name),function(x) head(x,1))` velocity is still being calculated from the previous person's co-ordinates...

Comment: I am unable to edit my comment above. The velocity is still not calculating properly using `dplyr` when I test the first sample for each person using `ddply(Calculations,.(Name),function(x) head(x,1))` Any suggestions?

Comment: Dunno it's working for me on the example data you gave.

Comment: I updated my original post... my issue stemmed as I had `dplyr` loaded first before `plyr` Thank you for the help!